# In Google Analytics, track which item and subsequent navigation path is used more

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

My knowledge of Google Analytics is pretty rusty. I am trying to set up tracking where I can know which Ad or button has been clicked, then as a next step, track which button has been clicked next. (The two clicks should be connected to each other.)

Basically we recently posted three ads on our site, to drive users to our premium pages for subscription. On the subscription page we have two buttons, the first button subscribes users to 7$ while second subscribes to 49$. We want to know the ad which is clicked the most and which subscription is clicked after that. This should be in order, like track which ad has been clicked and where does this user click next.

Is this implementation possible?

Answer (score 3):

This implementation is not only possible, it's trivial since this is exactly the kind of analysis meant to be conducted in GA and other analytics platforms.

You'd probably be best off with creating conversion funnels in GA and interpreting certain events as goals there.

You should start from ad click tracking (presuming the adds are on your site), then the 7 and 49 buttons clicks indicating which is clicked. And then I would also throw in proper enhanced ecommerce tracking for the checkout flow tracking to get the job done completely.

Now in GA, you create goals based on ad clicks and your purchase button clicks. Then, using these goals and occasional pageviews, you build conversion funnels. I would also suggest including the enhanced ecommerce conversions in that funnels.

Comment: This is better, thanks for your input.